# UICollectionViewCell Cleanup

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm currently experimenting with Nested UICollectionViews and I noticed (or could not find) a 'cleanup, WillBeDestroyed, WillBeDismissed' kind of hook for cells.

I believe I found one for 'CellWillAppear' if i'm correct but not the other way around.

I would mostly use it to unsubscribe from events (like button touches or application events)

I am using **Xamarin IOS** and I'm used to subscribe and unsubscribe from events:

```
UIButton button = new UIButton();

//On appearing / construction / ...
button.TouchUpInside += handle_touch;

//On disappearing / destruction / ...
button.TouchUpInside -= handle_touch;
```

So I guess my questions are the following:

**1. Does it exist?**

**2. If not, what alternatives are there?**

Comment: `PrepareForReuse()` is what you are looking for: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UICollectionReusableView.PrepareForReuse()/ On Apple Doc: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse

Comment: I'm actualy looking for the inverse (to unsubscribe to events)

Comment: You should be able to unsubscribe there too, no? I don't use Xamarin, but you may need to check if it has already subscribe before unsubscribing it. You subscribe in cellForRowAtIndexPath(), and unsubscribe in prepareForReuse().

Comment: True I could do that, good one to know.

Comment: `PrepareForReuse` is exactly what I use to unsubscribe to C# Events